# Fullcalendar header buttons not responsive?

Tags: button, mobile, header, fullcalendar, responsive

I configured Fullcalendar on my project, but I notice that on mobile, there is a problem with the layout of the buttons of the header, which is not at all aesthetic

**FullCalendar on PC :**

[image]

**FullCalendar on mobile :**

[image]

Is there anything to do to make it more aesthetic?

Comment: fullCalendar is not really intended for mobile use AFAIK, to be honest. Just too many buttons, too much text etc for it to be very usable (although you could argue that things like the Android calendar app do it well enough). I could be wrong but I don't think it's something the developers have really considered as a viable platform. So you'd probably have to change the CSS yourself to add some responsive design into a custom theme.

Answer (score 7):

This Fullcalender is not responsive so we have to make header forcefully responsive. Add below code in your  `ngOnInit()` function.

```
document.querySelector('style').textContent += "@media screen and (max-width:767px) { .fc-toolbar.fc-header-toolbar {flex-direction:column;} .fc-toolbar-chunk { display: table-row; text-align:center; padding:5px 0; } }";
```

Comment: Very useful! thnx

Answer (score 4):

I found a super simple solution that seems to work well and is just simple CSS:

```
@media screen and (max-width:767px) { .fc-toolbar.fc-header-toolbar {font-size: 60%}}
```

Answer (score 0):

If You are using only HTML, JavaScript and CSS as me.
I based this response from [Subham Debnath](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63649256/21240810) one, which is for those who are using Angular `ngOnInit()` method.

This below works fine with the default theme of FullCalendar or with Bootstrap 5 added.

Hope it helps you or newcomers.

Just need to add:

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {

    var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');
    var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
        // [...] Your code
    });
    calendar.render();

    document.querySelector('style').textContent += "@media screen and (max-width:767px) { .fc-toolbar.fc-header-toolbar {flex-direction:column;} .fc-toolbar-chunk { display: table-row; text-align:center; padding:5px 0; } }";
});
```